# Duplicating both lists and workflows

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow

I am creating a sharepoint site and list to coordinate our quarterly reporting requirements. I have a list for this quarter and the workflows I need set up, but when I hand this over to client services, they will need to be able to duplicate this setup every quarter going forward. I have seen that it is possible to copy workflows to a new list (which would be created from a template of the original), but this is likely too technically involved for others to do. What would be a better solution? I cannot make 'reuseable' workflows as they don't give me access to the fields of this specific list. The only alternate I could think of would be to archive the previous quarter (including all its content) and then rename the current one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ways to do that, require you to be somewhat technical (note, somewhat, not immensely).

1. The Visual Studio route: Create a site template with all of your needed lists and an associated workflow (as an activated feature). This site can be created with a simple add new site of template Quarterly Report. Takes more work upfront and some technical skills, but faster later on.
2. The SharePoint designer route: You would need to package the workflow and set the template as a solution that you can activate. Required to be associated with each list, requires a bit of work each time. Detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/30/packaging-list-site-and-reusable-workflow-and-how-to-deploy-the-package.aspx).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think I'll have to go the Visual Studio route as I am stuck using the 2010 software editions. Looking briefly online, both site definitions and web templates are mentioned are mentioned, which do you think would be most appropriate?